# intel - AX210 won't work after 21.04 upgrade

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

Just a couple of weeks ago, I installed my new AX210 Wi-Fi card since my old AC-8265 won't cooperate. I installed 18.04, then tried to update the kernel for the wifi card, since the minimum required kernel is 5.10. But then it didn't work properly, and 5Ghz didn't show up. I then removed it and then switched to 21.04.

Fast forward a couple of weeks, and the Wi-Fi card isn't working. I just updated it, and after a quick restart, it won't work. I have tried to install from the Intel website multiple times but that wouldn't work either. Can somebody help me?

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

https://pastebin.com/sr9tueVN

I used a pastebin because it wouldn't format correctly.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

https://pastebin.com/gVqRs8v8

Comment: May we also see a paste of: `dmesg | grep iwl` Thanks.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: @chili555 I just added the output

Comment: @guiverc the release date isn't far from now. Thanks for the help. I'm also running a dual-boot, and it works perfectly on Windows. I might move to Windows for a couple of days.

Comment: Please check here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: The beta was just announced (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/04/01/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-final-beta-released/) and currently the focus is on *bug hunting, bug reporting & bug fixing* so all issues with *hirsute* (what will be 21.04 on release) should be on bug trackers so they issues are fixed prior to release.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: @chili555 Fast boot was disabled in my bios and Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, after upgrading to the latest kernel.
I reverted to 5.11.0-11 kernel, and it works.

Comment: The latest 5.11.0-14 kernel fixed this bug. Ax210 now works.